# SQLalchemy: Engine/Connection disconnects after some hours of inactivity

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, database-connection

## Situation

I have a plotly-dash application running in a docker container (based on `python3.7-slim`).
The app is accessing a postgres database and visualizes the queried data.

However, if the app has not been used for some time (I would estimate around 24-48 hours. We first noticed this issue on mondays after nobody used the app during the weekend) i.e. if no data has been queried from the database, the app freezes and the logs show some errors related to the database.

I cannot fully access the logs, but they contain this error:

`AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute '_Connection_connection'`

and in the following, all the pieces of code which tried to query data from the database are stated (but not what exactly went wrong).

The problem was always solved with a restart of the app (and thus a new connection to the database)

## Assumption

As stated above, this *always* occured after a period of inactivity. So my assumption is, that the engine disconnects after some idle time

## Code Sample

For accessing the database, I have a `DatabaseConnection` class. The relevant part of the code contais something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

...

engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{passw}@{url}:{port}/{db_name}")
self.engine = engine.connect()

...
```

## Question

- What is the best solution for overcoming the issue of the disconnect after some inactivity?
- How could I possibly check whether the database connection is still active and if not, reconnect it somehow?
  -Is there a better way the access the database than through an `engine`-object?
- Is there something wrong with my approach in general?

Please let me know if you require further information. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'll try the approach described [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#disconnect-handling-pessimistic): Adding the keyword `pool_pre_ping=True` to the call of `create_engine`

Comment: `create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{passw}@{url}:{port}/{db_name}", pool_pre_ping=True)` did not solve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in my code. It should be

`self.engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{passw}@{url}:{port}/{db_name}")`

and the second line should be omitted. I misunderstood what `engine.connect()` is doing: It returns a `Connection` object (*not* an engine, as the attribute name suggests).

Then, for each query I execute, I use the context manager like this:

```
with self.engine.connect() as conn
  table1 = pd.read_sql_table("table1", con=conn)
```

That way, the `Connection` object is closed after it has been used. But the engine object may open new connections whenever necessary.

In my previous solution, die Connection was killed after some Idle time.

(Based on this [GitHub Discussion](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/6632))